# How to add text in edit text that remains there even though user types in it?

Tags: android, android-edittext, user-input

I have en edit text box that will ask the user for the date. I want to add dashes in the edit text box, so when the user enters the date they don't disappear. It would look like this:

DD-MM-YYYY

So, when the user enters the numbers for the date the dashes stay there. Hope someone can answer this for me. I am pretty new to Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you need a `TextChangedListener` in your `EditText` view, you add it like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

In those three methods you can handle the logic of keeping the dashes in position.

From an user point of view (and also from the developer point of view), that would be cumbersome, not to mention that it goes against the [design guidelines](http://goo.gl/sJinSs). You have two options. Either you split the `editText` view into three separate views rendering dashes between them with `TextViews`, or you use the solution suggested in the design guidelines, a `DatePicker` which looks like this:
[image: DatePicker screenshot]
When the user selects a date, you can edit a `TextView` to show the date or whatever you want to do. The code I used in the screenshot is the following:
Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private TextView textView;
        private DatePicker datePicker;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            this.textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            this.datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
            datePicker.init(2014, 4, 10, new OnDateChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    textView.setText(view.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + view.getMonth() + "-" + view.getYear());

                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:spinnersShown="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I disabled the `spinner` because it takes a lot of horizontal space.
You can also [show the picker as a dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) if you have to save the space in your view. Check the docs of the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) for more info.

Comment: +1 for using a DatePicker, I suggested the same thing. Not only is the custom implementation more cumbersome, but it obviously clashes with the design guidelines, too.

Comment: @VeselinRomic You are absolutely right. I updated my answer to emphasize your point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach? This should concatenate the user's input with your string or character, not delete it.

```
editText.setText(editText.getText() + "stuff you want to add");
```

Though, to be honest, on Android you should be using be using a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) for this, definitely not an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should need to use date picker for picking up the date,

If still, you requires so , then:

EditText edit_datePicker =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_pick);
edit_datePicker.settext("DD-MM-YYYY");
Now, what ever the user types appears after that.